# Mysql Update 2 columns from 2 different tables with extra condition

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I want to update two different columns from two different tables in mysql. This is the brief version of what I want to do.

In more detail I want to update a column from table 1 only if a condition is true. Otherwise I want to update a other column from table 1.

The same I want to do for table 2 and this should be all done in a single UPDATE statement.

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE `grouped_messages`
JOIN `messages` ON (`messages`.group_msg_id = 1) SET 
(CASE WHEN(`grouped_messages`.`conversation_partner1`=10) THEN `grouped_messages`.`deletion_status_partner1`=1
WHEN(`grouped_messages`.`conversation_partner2`=10) THEN `grouped_messages`.`deletion_status_partner2`=1 END),
(CASE WHEN(`messages`.`from`=10) THEN `messages`.`deletion_status_from`=1 
WHEN(`messages`.`to`=10) THEN `messages`.`deletion_status_to`=1 END);
```

but this is not working. Does anybody know a solution, which would work for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do an assignment within a CASE expression. Your `SET` clause is invalid. It needs to be `SET column = expression`.

To have the column conditionally updated; that is, to have the column *not* updated, have the expression return the *current value* of the column.

Let's use an alias of `g` for `grouped_messages`.

When the condition you are checking is true, you want the `SET` clause to be equivalent to:

```
SET g.deletion_status_partner1 = 1
```

When the condition is *not* true, you want to assign the current value of the column to itself, so the `SET` clause to equivalent to:

```
SET g.deletion_status_partner1 = g.deletion_status_partner1
```

To get that, you could do something like this:

```
 SET g.deletion_status_partner1
     = CASE WHEN g.conversation_partner1 = 10
       THEN 1
       ELSE g.deletion_status_partner1 -- existing column value
       END
```

To modify an additional column, you'd need to add to the `SET` clause

```
   , g.deletion_status_partner2
     = CASE WHEN some_other_condition
       THEN new_value
       ELSE g.deletion_status_partner2 -- existing column value
       END
```

(I haven't checked anything else in your statement; I only highlight the most obvious issue, and how to get an update statement to do "conditional" assignment.)

Comment: NOTE: be careful with additional references to a column that is being assigned a value. Unlike other databases, MySQL does *not* preserve the  previous value for a later reference; and MySQL doesn't guarantee that a reference will return the previous value, or the newly assigned value. (MySQL doesn't guarantee a particular order of operations. I don't think this is a concern in your statement. It would be a concern, however, if some other CASE expression referenced the `g.deletion_status_partner1` column, which is the target of an assignment.)